# Mostrar solo el año y el mes en Select option en Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy buscando resolver un problema, necesito mostrar en mi vista create de laravel un select con el mes y año, no asi con el día, estaba probando con carbon pero me trae algo de una forma distinta... no se si alguien tiene algún ejemplo o tips de como lograr esto! utilizo Laravel 5.5

- Enero 2019
- Febrero 2019
- Marzo 2019
- Abril 2019
- Mayo 2019
- Junio 2019
- Julio 2019
- Agosto 2019
- Septiembre 2019
- Octubre 2019
- Noviembre 2019
- Diciembre 2019
- Enero 2020

Este es parte de mi código en mi controlador

Controller.php

```
 public function create()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $now->year;
        $now->month;
        $Egresos    = Egresos::all();
        $clientes   = Cliente::all();
        $proveedores= Proveedores::orderBy('nombreproveedor')->pluck('nombreproveedor','id');
        $fondos= CustomerParameter::orderBy('nombreparametro')
                ->where('tipodeparametro', 'Gastos comunes')
                ->pluck('nombreparametro', 'nombreparametro');
        return view("admin.egresos.create", compact ("Egresos","proveedores","clientes","now" ,"fondos"));
    }
```

y esto en mi vista create.blade.php tengo este codigo!

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="fechacobro">Seleccione mes a cobrar</label>
         {!! Form::select('fechacobro', $now, null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione fecha a cobrar','required']) !!}
         </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

---

Lo tengo así en la vista

```
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="fechacobro">Seleccione mes a cobrar</label>
         {!! Form::select('fechacobro', $fechaFormateada, null, ['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Seleccione fecha a cobrar','required']) !!}
         </div>
    </div>
```

Asi en el controlador

```
public function create()
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        $fechaBase =  Carbon::now();
        $fechaNombreMes = $fechaBase->monthName;
        $fechaAnio = $fechaBase->year;
        $fechaFormateada = $fechaNombreMes." ".$fechaAnio;
        $Egresos    = Egresos::all();
        $clientes   = Cliente::all();
        $proveedores= Proveedores::orderBy('nombreproveedor')->pluck('nombreproveedor','id');
        $fondos= CustomerParameter::orderBy('nombreparametro')
                ->where('tipodeparametro', 'Gastos comunes')
                ->pluck('nombreparametro', 'nombreparametro');
        return view("admin.egresos.create", compact ("Egresos","proveedores","clientes","now" ,"fondos","fechaFormateada"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te coloco este ejemplo para darle formato a la fecha, obteniendo la salida solo con el nombre del mes y el año:

**Obtén la fecha completa, aquí podría ser el valor que obtienes de la consulta a tu BD**

```
$fechaBase = now();
```

**Obtenemos algo como lo siguiente en la consola**

```
Illuminate\Support\Carbon @1574375036 {#3009
     date: 2019-11-21 22:23:56.657612 UTC (+00:00),
   }
```

**Ahora obtenemos solo el nombre del mes de la fecha que ya tenemos**

```
$fechaFormateada = $fechaBase->formatLocalized("%B %A");
```

**Obteniendo como salida algo similar a esto**

> "November 2019"

**Referencias**

- [Carbon docs localization](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)